# How to use local media player of Nokia Asha 311 S40 FT device

Tags: java-me, media-player

If I would like to use the local media player of Nokia S40 FT device in my application for mp3 audio. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

have you try to use platform Request?

you can find something useful in here http://www.developer.nokia.com/Resources/Library/Java/#!developers-guides/invoking-applications/invoking-applications-in-java-me.html

Comment: platformRequest() does not give you control of the native player. It only lets you request that the device opens a file, as I wrote in the comment in the previous answer. You can request the device to open an mp3 file. If it works, it will probably open the native player, but that's it. You can't stop the player or close it again. That's for the user to do. And when he does, the phone won't magically jump back to the app that requested the player to start.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote this a while back:
http://indiegamemusic.com/help.php?id=1

Should be what you need.

Comment: thanx.. is there anyway to pause the audio? there seems to be only two fuctionalities start and stop.

Comment: There are no pause() function no. Some devices pauses the track when you call stop() though. Calling start() again will resume the track where it left of. But other devices rewinds the track to the beginning when calling stop(). Yet another one of those things that was never specified in detail, so manufacturers did different things.
You can experiment with getMediaTime() and setMediaTime in order to create a pause function. Getting the media time before stopping, and setting it again right after calling start().

Comment: ok thanx. One last thing I would like to ask, can we use the default media player interface of asha 311 in our app?

Comment: You can't access native stuff with JavaME. However, by calling platformRequest() you can request the device to execute a command. For example dial a phone number or open a URL. Such a URL can in some cases also be path to a local file. So if you do something like platformRequest("file://c/some/path/music.mp3") there's a chance the device will startup the local media player. But you just can't control it from JavaME.

Comment: @MinhaajAnwaar have you find solution to this problem?? I wabt to use native media player to play video through my application.

Comment: No i didnt find the solution Patel. we can use native media player with JavaME. this is the limitaion.

Answer (score 0):

you may use method from com.nokia.mid.impl.jms.core.Launcher:
`String url = "E:\\mymp3.mp3";
 Launcher.handleContent(url);`
But its required manufacturer or operator domain certificate. But you may open full access for filesystem from JAVA-apps (like a Root in android).